# ipython notebook images not seen in pdf conversion

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, xelatex, nbconvert

When I try to convert the ipynb file to pdf my pictures in the ipynb don't make it to the pdf at all. There is no sign of them and the markdown table doesn't get rendered properly. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: What kind of images are these? Are they in outputs, or markdown cells? Embedded in the document, or referencing external files?

Answer (score -1):

Please see the following code of auto generated Latex file created by Jupyter Notebook (ipynb) file. You can open the .tex extension file in the editor and go to the line 32 or 33 where you will find the bold line and comment it out. Your problem will be partially solved.
Code:
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
% Set max figure width to be 80% of text width, for now hardcoded.
(%)\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=.8\maxwidth]{#1}}
After commenting it out, find the image attachment command in .tex file. When you find that lines where compiler stops usually. replace the line of:
\adjustmentbox
with:
\includegraphics[scale=0.5 or whatever you desire]{yourimage.png}

Hope it solves your problem, mine is solved and i generated pdf from latex including graphics.

Answer (score -2):

just try the below code in **markdown**

```
![title](imagename.png)
```

Make sure that the image you are trying to save in ipython notebook is in the same location as of the notebook